# Управление пользователями и группами в Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: права, ubuntu

Доброго времени суток!  Не могу найти пункт управления пользователями и группами. В предыдущих версиях Ubuntu он был  в настройках пользователя (кнопка "Дополнительные параметры"), ![Параметры пользователя][1]там можно было в деталях настроить права каждого пользователя, а сейчас есть только два варианта: "администратор" и "обычный". Подскажите, как можно детально разграничить права пользователей, добавлять их в группы и т.п. Может есть какой-то другой gui для таких настроек, который не включен в текущую Ubuntu.*Если быть точнее, то мне нужно разрешить обычному пользователю видеть примонтированный раздел NTFS.*Спасибо!  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGn42.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установите gnome-system-tools

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

Теперь в строке поиска Ubuntu наберите слово пользователи (или группы) и кликните по иконке программы. Либо просто запустите из консоли

```
users-admin
```

Comment: Оно самое. Большое спасибо!  С наступающими праздниками!